# Android cliackable list view crashing

Tags: android, listview, button, onclicklistener

I'm trying to get a Listview to become clickable, but it crashes right away if there's any method/function being called, like the toast();

```
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, arrayListCarros);  
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );      
    db.close();



    mainListView.setClickable(true);
    mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            toast(position);

      }
    });
```

Comment: Post stack trace

Comment: what is there inside ur list view .

Answer (score 0):

```
 mainListView.setClickable(true);
    mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(activityname.this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new intent(activityName.this,targerActivity.class);
            activityName.this.startActivity(intent);    
  }
```

Comment: Right, that worked great, but now I'm trying to call a new intent like this:      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {                         itEdicao = new Intent(listagemcarro.this, edicao.class);      startActivity(itEdicao);} and it's crashing me again

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, ActivityThatYouWantToStart.class); Please add Log of your Exception.

Comment: 11-19 22:09:01.177: W/dalvikvm(1251): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
11-19 22:09:01.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1251): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-19 22:09:01.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1251): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.trabalhosql/com.example.trabalhosql.edicao}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-19 22:09:01.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)

Comment: 11-19 22:09:01.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
11-19 22:09:01.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
11-19 22:09:01.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
11-19 22:09:01.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-19 22:09:01.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

Comment: 11-19 22:09:01.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-19 22:09:01.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 22:09:01.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-19 22:09:01.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-19 22:09:01.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Comment: 11-19 22:09:01.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-19 22:09:01.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1251): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-19 22:09:01.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):  at com.example.trabalhosql.edicao.onCreate(edicao.java:42)
11-19 22:09:01.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-19 22:09:01.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)

Comment: 11-19 22:09:01.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):  ... 11 more
11-19 22:09:01.196: I/dalvikvm(1251): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
11-19 22:09:01.196: E/dalvikvm(1251): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied

Comment: Yeah, I actually made a button just to check if the activity would show, and it did.

Comment: I think you should read a android book for beginners. Sorry i cant help you under the circumstances.